# Pull-up resistors on I2C port

Tags: microcontroller, resistors, sensor, i2c, pullup

[image]

Hi everyone, I am confuse about I2C pull-up resistors. I use 4 I2C sensors. I am not sure is it true that pull-up resistors count. I use every sensors for pull-up resistors. If I use just one I2C port (I mean one port for all sensors) is it enough?

Also, I heard "Pull-up resistors are not require because STM32F already have one." is that true? Please help me about it. I will be really appriciated.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Graphs for the bus pull-up resistor values at different speeds and are given in the I2C bus specification. Take a look at that, you'll find it on the internet. Incidentally, please don't be tempted to post lots of little questions around the same problem as the site's not a help forum, it's a Q&A site. Again, welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The count of pull-up resistors does not matter, it's the combined value of them that matters. You have four resistors, two 10k and two 4k7. That adds up to 1.6k of equivalent total resistance, equating to about 2mA of current needed to drive the bus. It is within I2C specification and it's fine if all the chips have strong enough IO stages to drive that current, so you must check the datasheets of each chip, as most chips can but some special chips may not be able to dribe that. In practice no one would use four separate resistors but a single resistor with suitable size. So yes, it is enough to use only one resistor.

Yes the MCU contains software switchable pull-ups on IO pins so it is not a lie, but saying that it does not require external resistors is just not true in practice. In some rare cases they might be fine, but it is so unlikely that in practice, there is no reason to leave out external pull-up resistors. The pull-ups in STM32 MCUs are approximately 40k which is generally unsuitable for I2C but it depends on many factors if you can use resistors as high as 40k in your application.

Answer (score 8):

> *If I use just one I2C port (I mean one port for all sensors) is it
> enough?*

You only need one set of resistors per I2C port: -

[image]

Image from [EDN](https://www.edn.com/design-calculations-for-robust-i2c-communications/).

> *I heard "Pull-up resistors are not require because STM32F already have
> one." is that true?*

It may have pull-up resistors internal to the device but, are they the right value for the data speeds you need? You also need to be able to adjust the resistor values depending on data speed and bus capacitance ([see here](https://community.silabs.com/s/article/i2c-pull-up-resistor-calculation?language=en_US#:%7E:text=These%20pull%2Dups%20would%20draw,each%20during%20SCL%2FSDA%20low) and [here](https://atman-iot.com/blog/i2c-pull-up-calculator/)). It's unlikely that whatever internal pull-ups are available, they will suit most requirements.

Comment: Thx a lot for help :)